# Removing tests from unittest suite

Tags: python, unit-testing

In order to run all my unittests I use following script where test_files is a list of strings of my testfiles:

```
for test_file in test_files:
    test_file = test_file[:-3]
    module = __import__(test_file)
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            if str(obj).startswith("<class 'test_"):
                suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(obj))
```

How can I remove single tests from the suite afterwards (not all tests from a testfile)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally ended up creating a new suite and added all tests except the ones I want to skip. In order for the test to be listed as skipped I created a dummy SkipCase class.

```
class SkipCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        raise unittest.SkipTest("Test would take to long.")

new_suite = unittest.TestSuite()

blacklist = [
    'test_some_test_that_should_be_skipped',
    'test_another_test_that_should_be_skipped'
]

for test_group in suite._tests:
    for test in test_group:
        if test._testMethodName in blacklist:
            testName = test._testMethodName
            setattr(test, testName, getattr(SkipCase(), 'runTest'))
        new_suite.addTest(test)
```

Comment: Your solution is good, however during run it will still call setup/teardown functions.. to resolve this I've changed your setattr method like this: `setattr(test, testName, unittest.skip(reason)(getattr(test, testName)))` possibly after test if you agree, you may update your answer !

Answer (score 2):

You can use this skip decorator on a class or method basis:

```
import unittest
@unittest.skipUnless(sys.platform.startswith("win"), "requires Windows")
class MarketTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        return
    @unittest.skip("Skipping market basics test")
    def test_market_libraries(self):
        return
```